# Is there a way to use a windows app in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

Is there a way to use a windows app in Ubuntu 14.04?  Our company's new Expense Report app does not have a Linux version as before. Our choices are now either windows or mac.

Answer (score 1):

You might get away with Wine - a compatibility layer that will run some Windows software, depending on the type of the app: https://www.winehq.org/

Alternatively, you could run windows itself inside a virtual machine on your Ubuntu box: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualMachines

I guess my final suggestion would be to dual-boot the machine: http://www.howtogeek.com/187789/dual-booting-explained-how-you-can-have-multiple-operating-systems-on-your-computer/